# adding (not overwriting a class) for a form generated by the form_for helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you add an additional class to a rails generated form? This is as opposed to overwriting the existing class as explained here:

[How do you override the class name in the form_for helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881645/how-do-you-override-the-class-name-in-the-form-for-helper)

Using :class => "foo" does not work.

Comment: Why don't you just add the original class in manually and do it that way?

Comment: The html for the form element is generated by the rails helper, so it doesn't have a preexisting class, only what you give it. Are you using formtastic or some other type of gem that affects the form code? And when you say that `:class => "foo"` does not work, do you mean that it doesn't assign the class "foo" to the element at all?

Comment: @Bradley, I could do that but it's ugly so i thought there would be a better way.

Comment: @ellawren, actually no the default rails form helper does assign a default class, I think it is {resource name}_new, and :class => "foo" has no effect

Comment: You should probably post the code you're using to generate the form...

Comment: Thanks, I just did it with the manual addition, was just surprised since I though :class => was a pretty established convention so wanted to make sure I wasnt missing anything.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this other than doing it manually? I have the same problem:
`form_for(resource)`automatically adds the appropriate class (e.g. new_resource or edit_resource). But `form_for(resource, {html:{class:'myclass'}})` **overrides** the above class and just outputs 'myclass'. How can I **add** 'myclass' to the Rails-generated class 'new_resource' or 'edit_resource' on the form?

Comment: One way you can do it is with something like `html: { class: "#{dom_class(resource, action_name)} myclass" }`. `dom_class` is the method that `form_for` calls internally (through `apply_form_for_options!`). Problem with using `action_name` is that it will change if the form is rerendered by a different action, ie. `create` or `update` if there are validation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comment's advice I did this via manual addition of the original class