# How to add a class to the form_for helper in a Rails 4 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, form-for

I'm using bootstrap CCS to style my Rails 4 app, but cannot figure out how to add a class to the form when using the form_for helper. I have followed the suggestions on several other threads without success. Two such threads...

- [How do you override the class name in the form_for helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881645/how-do-you-override-the-class-name-in-the-form-for-helper)
- [adding (not overwriting a class) for a form generated by the form_for helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403428/adding-not-overwriting-a-class-for-a-form-generated-by-the-form-for-helper)

The app works as it should per the instructions, but I want it to look good too. Here is the working code and have commented out the first line as it does not add the additional class to the form as I need it to.

- https://github.com/Brian-Boyd/TheIronYard/blob/master/03week-day4/patient/app/views/patients/_form.html.haml

Can anyone help with this challenge? Hopefully there is some smart Rails developers available to help out today.

Comment: Did you get any error when using this line `form_for @patient, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"} do |f|` which you have commented?

Comment: No error. The page still loads, but when I look at the source code, the class is not added.

Comment: This is very strange as I just tried again and it works. The class has been replaced. I did not do anything different than before I wrote the question.

Comment: Hmm,might you restarted the server?

Comment: This also works i think so `form_for @patient, {:html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}} do |f|`

Comment: I had restarted the server, but did not see the change. I shut everything down and when I started it back up is when I saw the change.

Comment: Ok,anyways.I added my answer to give you some more useful info.Please appreciate it if you satisfied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have got your answer,though these are some points might help you

`form_for` with class name in haml:

```
= form_for @patient, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"} do |f|
```

it can also be written as

```
= form_for @patient, {:html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}} do |f|
```

but it couldn't be written as

```
- form_for @patient, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"} do |f| #it gives error.
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Pavan! This really help as I was able to go in and drew up the form nice.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Pavan's answer in Rails 4 you can simply write it this way **if you are using a form_tag**:

```
= form_tag some_path, method: 'get', class: 'some-class' do
```

This worked for me.