# Applying a Bootstrap class to form_for in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to apply the bootstrap class "form-horizontal center" to my rails form_for helper as follows:

```
<%= form_for(@customer), :html => {:class => "form-horizontal center"} do |f| %>
```

I am getting a syntax error.

I have looked at this with no luck:  [How to add a class to the form_for helper in a Rails 4 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184553/how-to-add-a-class-to-the-form-for-helper-in-a-rails-4-app)

Any ideas?

Comment: Please, print the error that you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= form_for @customer, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal center"} do |f| %>
```

Remove brackets from `@customer` or move closing bracket before `do`:

```
<%= form_for(@customer, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal center"}) do |f| %>
```